# What does these R variable icons mean?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm wondering what these icons mean.

[image]

I'm using the following packages

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
library(gplots)
library(httpuv)
```

I use the variable in this call

```
ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token, paginate_query = T)
```

Can someone explain:

- What the icons mean
- Why there are 2 for this one variable

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using R Studio with R? If so, the following link should explain what the symbols mean. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion. Broadly speaking, each symbol gives you an autocomplete option with the type of symbol representing the type of object you can autocomplete.

I believe the duplication of symbols for your ga.data frame is a bug with the current R Studio - it shouldn't make a difference which one you select, however.

Comment: I'm indeed using R studio with R (Version 0.99.451).
Thank you for this clear explanation. I'll assume it's a bug then.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

They're found [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion). Image copied below for convenience

[image]